Invariance of set distances with $\varepsilon$-neighbourhoods
I am trying to prove something involving distances between sets which I believe to be true (at least intuitively), but can't seem to get to the end. The situation is as follows. Let $\Omega$ be a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $K \subset \Omega$ be compact. For any set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $r > 0$, define
$$A_{\text{ball}}(r) = \bigcup_{a \in A} B(a, r)$$
to be the $r$-neighbourhood of $A$. Suppose there is another compact set $K' \subset \Omega$ containing $K$ such that $\text{dist}(K', \partial\Omega) = \text{dist}(K, \partial\Omega)$ and the closure $\overline{K'_\text{ball}(r)}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $r > 0$ is contained in $\Omega$. Then it follows that
$$\text{dist}\left(K'_\text{ball}(r), \partial \Omega\right) = \text{dist}\left(K_\text{ball}(r), \partial\Omega\right). \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Here, $\text{dist}(A, B) = \inf\{|a - b| : a \in A, b \in B\}$. The reason why I think this is true is because intuitively, what this says is that if I have two sets that are of the same distance away from the boundary of a set that contains them both, then if I uniformly fatten up the first two sets by the same sufficiently small amount, the new distances to the boundary should change by the same amount.
What I have tried to prove (after drawing some pictures) is that $\text{dist}\left(K_\text{ball}(r), \partial\Omega\right) = \text{dist}(K, \partial\Omega) - r$ and after playing with the infimums, I've managed to get $\text{dist}\left(K_\text{ball}(r), \partial\Omega\right) \geq \text{dist}(K, \partial\Omega) - r$. But I can't seem to get the other inequality so that equality is established. I would expect that this reasoning doesn't depend on $K$ so that we would also get $\text{dist}\left(K'_\text{ball}(r), \partial\Omega\right) = \text{dist}(K', \partial\Omega) - r$, and then everything would follow from my assumptions. So could I get suggestions on how to obtain $\text{dist}\left(K_\text{ball}(r), \partial\Omega\right) \leq \text{dist}(K, \partial\Omega) - r$, if it is in fact true?
Finally, if all of the above holds, would \eqref{1} still be true if I replaced $A_\text{ball}(r)$ with a cube neighbourhood
$$A_\text{cube}(r_1, \dots, r_n) = \bigcup_{a \in A} \prod_{i = 1}^n \{x_i \in \mathbb{R} : |x_i - a_i| < r_i\}$$
and kept the analogous assumptions throughout?

Suppose that $\mathrm{dist}(A,B)>r>0$, where $A$ and $B$ are two disjoint nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $N$ be the $r$-neighbourhood of $A$. You can already prove that $\mathrm{dist}(N,B)\geq\mathrm{dist}(A,B)-r$.
Given any $\epsilon>0$ and $0<\alpha<1$, pick $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that
$$|a-b|<\mathrm{dist}(A,B)+\epsilon.$$
Pick $x\in B(a,r)$ from the segment joining $a$ and $b$, such that $|a-x|=\alpha r$. Then $x\in N$, so
$$\mathrm{dist}(N,B)\leq|x-b|=|a-b|-\alpha r<\mathrm{dist}(A,B)+\epsilon-\alpha r.$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary,
$$\mathrm{dist}(N,B)\leq\mathrm{dist}(A,B)-\alpha r.$$
But $\alpha$ is also arbitrary, so
$$\mathrm{dist}(N,B)\leq\mathrm{dist}(A,B)-r.$$
If you replace balls with cubes, then the statement does not hold. For a counterexample, let $\Omega$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ with its origin removed. Put $K=\{(1,0)\}$, and let $K'$ be the unit circle, so their distances from the origin are both $1$. Consider open squares with side length $\sqrt{2}$. Such a square centered at $(1,0)$ has distance $1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ from the origin. But such a square centered at $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\in K'$ has distance $0$ from the origin.

Thanks for your answer! Your proof clears up all my confusion regarding the distance from an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood to the boundary. I don't think your counterexample holds though, because the closure of your cube neighbourhood of the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ includes the origin (unless I'm mistaken) and so is not a subset of $\Omega$. Apologies if that assumption was left buried in my walls of text in the question.

@MathsMatador It doesn't matter, a slightly smaller square would do.

Yes you're right. This raises the question of what extra assumptions would guarantee that (1) in my question holds for cube neighbourhoods. For example, could I ask if you think it would be true if $K'$ was additionally the convex hull of $K$?
